# python command line interface with shell prompt

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, command-line-interface

I am researching into a python CLI application with a shell prompt. To clarify, I am looking for something which supports 2 functionalities.

1) provides a shell prompt & auto complete on the commands like how "cmd" module supports. for eg: the "do_" prefixed commands. ( do_xyz: do_abc. )

2) provides support for multiple sub-commands and options. for eg:

```
$ python my_prog_prompt.py
(my_prog_prompt)> cmd1 subcmd1 subsubcmd1
(my_prog_prompt)> cmd1 subcmd1 subsubcmd2
(my_prog_prompt)> cmd1 subcmd2 subsubcmd1 -x -y
(my_prog_prompt)> cmd2 subcmd1 
(my_prog_prompt)> cmd2 subcmd1 
(my_prog_prompt)> exit
$
```

I found the "cmd" module above to be overly simplistic. Since it does not supports multiple sub-commands. With Cement CLI i could see it supports the multiple commands/subcommands and options very well, but does not have a shell/prompt interface. Can the "cmd" module be extended to support the above ? Or is there another available framework or module i can use, which will give me the above support.

Much thanks.

Comment: have you looked at the `readline` and the `rlcompleter` modules ?

Answer (score 0):

Posibly late for an answer but I was looking for a similar option and this is what I've ended up implementing:

1. Create this wrapper

```python
def parseargs( f ):
    def wrapper(s, arg ):
        args={ 0: f.__name__ }
        i=0 
        for a in arg.split():
            i+=1
            if i>0 and '=' in a:
                args[i] = a.split('=', 1)
            else:
                args[i] = a
       return f(s, args)
    wrapper.__doc__ = f.__doc__
return wrapper
```

2. Use it like this inside your class:

```python
@parseargs
def do_setvar_for_group(self, args):
    'setvar_for_group <group> <var1=value1> : Sets a variable for a group'
    command = args[0]     # command = 'setvar_for_group'
    group = args[1]       # group = 'example_group'
    var_key = arg[2][0]   # var_key = 'myvar'
    var_value = arg[2][1] # var_value = 'example'
#
# You would get this values by executing:
# prompt> setvar_for_group example_group myvar=example
```